# Toggle Voice Control with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, accessibility, voice-control

Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle Voice Control on and off on a Mac running Big Sur? Not Dictation, mind you... Voice Control (under *System Preferences > Accessibility > Voice Control*).

[image: voice control]

I've looked in the Accessibility section of the Keyboard Shortcuts preference pane. Ain't nothing there. It's also (inexplicably) not an option in Accessibility Shortcuts either.

I use Voice Control regularly but not consistently, so I tend to keep it disabled until I need it. It's a hassle to dive into System Preferences every time I want to enable it.

Before you ask, the reason that I don't keep it on all the time (but asleep) is that the floating microphone window is **always** in the way of something on my MacBook's screen.

I've Googled and Googled and Googled for this. Nada. I have minimal interest in writing an AppleScript/Automator thing to do this... too fragile and finicky for me... but I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>
- Assumes that the target *checkbox* has once before been manually toggled to deal with the permission dialog that appears the first time the target *checkbox* has been manually toggled.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be use in a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* that has been assigned a *keyboard shortcut* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, however, it's been my experience that it is better to use any of the *third-party applications* that are capable of running **AppleScript** *code* and assigning a *global keyboard shortcut*.

- As an example, I use [**FastScripts**](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/) for some tasks, as well as [**Hammerspoon**](http://www.hammerspoon.org) for other tasks. (I am not associate with the developers of these products, just a satisfied user.)

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the Accessibility pane. 

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"


tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        tell window 1
            
            --  # Wait for the target UI element to be available.
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists scroll area 1
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            
            --  # Select Voice Control.
            
            try
                select (rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 ¬
                    whose value of static text 1 of ¬
                    UI element 1 is "Voice Control")
            end try
            
            --  # Wait for the target UI element to be available.
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists checkbox 3 of group 1
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            
            --  # Click checkbox Enable Voice Control.
            
            click checkbox 3 of group 1
            
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.2

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* uses **UI Scripting**, which can be kludgy at times, and assuming **System Preferences** is normally already closed the *script* will cause the **System Preferences** icon to bounce one time it the **Dock**.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: This works! While I'm not thrilled about using an AppleScript that relies on UI elements (_What happens when Apple changes the System Prefs interface?_), it's a good solution while it works. Anyway, I simply copied and pasted this script into a Better Touch Tool action and it worked first try. Amazing. Many thanks. Thanks also for commenting your code. That's helpful too.

Comment: @Sam, RE: "_(What happens when Apple changes the System Prefs interface?)_" --  Then as the usual protocol goes, the _code_ will need to be adjusted to work with that version of **macOS**. It's really not a big deal and if you need help modifying it, then ask a question and I'm sure it will get answered.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough.