# Toggle Voice Control with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: mac, automator

I found this post from 2 years ago:

[Toggle Voice Control with a keyboard shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423564/toggle-voice-control-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

And it's a great solution, I imported it into automator easily, but running the script only seems to open system preferences and navigate to Accessibility settings, it doesn't actually navige to or turn on voice control. Is there any way somebody could let me know what to edit in the script wo it works? I'm on MacOs Monterey 12.6.7

Thank you so much!

This is the script code:

````
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the Accessibility pane. 

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"


tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        tell window 1
            
            --  # Wait for the target UI element to be available.
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists scroll area 1
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            
            --  # Select Voice Control.
            
            try
                select (rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 ¬
                    whose value of static text 1 of ¬
                    UI element 1 is "Voice Control")
            end try
            
            --  # Wait for the target UI element to be available.
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists checkbox 3 of group 1
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            
            --  # Click checkbox Enable Voice Control.
            
            click checkbox 3 of group 1
            
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.2

tell application "System Preferences" to quit ```
````